# cython in jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, cython, jupyter-notebook

I am getting errors when loading a Cython file in Jupyter Notebook.  Any ideas?

```
%load_ext Cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
```

Just a simple error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-7e39dc7f561b>", line 5
    cimport numpy as np
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you use cython code in special magic cells. You define a cython cell by starting your cell with `%%cython`

Comment: ```ERROR: Cell magic `%%cython` not found.```

Answer (score 20):

After reading the [docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version3.html?highlight=cython%20magic) -- I used two separate cells.  The first one is just:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

Then my import statements

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
```

Comment: Perhaps you miss c when import cimport 
```
cimport numpy as **c**np
```