# JupyterLab cimport of cython .pxd

Tags: python, pandas, cython, jupyter-lab

Similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768637/cython-in-jupyter-notebook) I'm trying to `cimport` .pxd file like so:

```py
%load_ext cython
```

```py
%%cython
cimport pandas._libs.util
```

But get `Error compiling Cython file:`

```
'pandas/_libs/util.pxd' not found
```

But this file [exists](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/util.pxd). Or should I correct the path to it somehow or else?

Comment: You've checked that it exists on your PC and not just on github?

Comment: I've checked as you suggested in `site_packages/pandas/_libs` and looks like all `.pyx` and `.pxd` are gone after compillation - only `.py` and `.so` are there. So are desired '.pxd' not accessible this way?

Comment: My impression is that these are treated as implementation details rather than public interfaces users should be able to access and so they aren't installed. [Here's a question from a few weeks ago with basically the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776685/can-you-cimport-an-so-file). I'm afraid I don't know a better solution to ensure these files are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidW proposed it seems like `.pxd` files are simply not installed during `pip install pandas` due to its internal purposes.

So in order to get access to `.pxd` files (and any others) from jupyter notebook on may use following:
clone github [repo](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) and install from cloned folder in develop (editable) mode:

```py
python setup.py develop
```

This way installed in 'lib/python/site-packages' will be created a file `pandas.egg-link` which is simply a link to cloned repo, so `.pxd` files are now accessible with

```
%%cython
cimport pandas._libs.util as util
```